# Delphi dbedit or tedit to ACCESS field

Tags: delphi, ms-access, field

I want to make one trick: That in Delphi will be a dbedit or tedit, and I want to connect it with a field in MS ACCESS. Function: Start program, write something to dbedit or tedit, push button "write" and then what I wrote to the dbedit or tedit, it will be in ACCESS Field, and then next time to add more info to ms access, but how to do it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately your wish isn't automatically our command. Try to refrase your question into another more kind and patient tone.

Comment: Start with some tutorials found on the Internet on how to work with ADO and Delphi. here is an [example](http://www.podgoretsky.com/ftp/docs/Delphi/D5/dg/ado_comp.html). good luck.

Comment: We are not going to write your program for us. Please ask a specific question about a specific problem.

Answer (score 3):

A mini manual Delphi - MS Access application:

- Start MS Access, choose an empty DB (e.g. `C:\DB1.mdb`), create a new table in design view, and add the following fields:

  - `TestID` of type Auto number,
  - `TestText` of type Memo,
- Set the `TestID` field as the primary key with a click at the key icon,
- Save the table as `Test`,
- Create a new project in Delphi and drag a `TADOConnection` onto the form,
- Set the `ConnectionString` property to: `Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\DB1.mdb;Persist Security Info=False`,
- Set the `LoginPrompt` property to `False`,
- Set the `Connected` property to `True`,
- Drag a `TADOTable` component onto the form,
- Set the `Connection` property to `ADOConnection1`,
- Set the `TableName` property to `Test`,
- Set the `Active` property to `True`,
- Drag a `TDataSource` onto the form,
- Set the `DataSet` property to `ADOTable1`,
- Drag a `TDBEdit` onto the form and set `Readonly=True`, `DataSource=DataSource1` and `DataField=TestID`,
- Drag a `TDBMemo` onto the form and set `DataSource=DataSource1` and `DataField=TestText`,
- Drag a `TDBNavigator` onto the form and set `DataSource=DataSource1`,
- For a full view of all records, drag a `TDBGrid` onto the form and set `DataSource=DataSource1`,
- Save the project and hit F9 to run your application,
- Play with the navigator buttons to scroll through and add, edit or remove your records,
- Et voilà.

[Source](http://www.nldelphi.com/Forum/showpost.php?p=1948&postcount=3)